# Calling a fullcalendar method/callback from another file

Tags: jquery, local-storage, fullcalendar

I'm having a few issues implementing my fullCalendar example since I'm a noob to javascript, jquery and the fullcalendar itself.
The short summary:
My project struture is the index html which gets the js libraries I need and has only a div containing the fullcalendar, a calendar.js file where I keep my fullcalendar configurations and where I get the events from an external source and the localstorage and finally an events.js file where I implement event creation through selecting time blocks and store them to the localstorage. The files SHOULD be separated like this, in order to keep the code for options and the code for the selecting and storing separated, organized and clean.
Also the google calendar events are also meant to be an alternate event source to the locally stored ones.

So here are my issues numbered:

1. The select callback from events.js doesn't work (I have tried it
   with    $(document).ready() as well) if it is in that separate file
   (while it    is included in just one it works fine as expected). How
   can I    successfully call this method?
2. How can I immediately render an event from the localstorage.getItem() when the page loads? (This is also meant to be separated later)
3. Why is my localstorage.getItem() in the calendar.js getting the
   items stored repeated 3 times? (This one is really bugging me out)

**EDIT:** Solved a few issues on my own (but following the suggestions of the 1st comment):
How I stand now:

1. Events are now created successfully on selection with the code
   separated from the main calendar.js file from events.js
2. **I still need to render the events from localStorage when the page loads (not from the separate file as I was doing, silly
   goose)**
3. The localStorage.getItem() no longer repeats the stored events 3 times... I needed an array, silly me again.

**UPDATED CODE:**
Here is my code for calendar.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        //Retrieves the function that allows events to be created by selecting cells on the calendar
        select: eventCreaterOnSelection
    });
});
```

And here is my updated code for events.js:

```
eventCreaterOnSelection = function(start, end, allDay) {
        // After selection user will be promted to renter the title for the event and if it is an all day event.
        var title = prompt("Event Title:"); //Setting the title for the event
        var allDay;
        //This is an array to store the event attributes
        var save = [];
        //If the user inputs a title then the event will be saved otherwise nothing will occur
        if (title) {
            //First we check and store if it is an all day event
            allDay = confirm("All Day event?");
            //Create the event object with a method to store it in Local Storage
            var newEvent = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay,
                //Define Local storage storing and making it readable (stringify for JSON)
                save: localStorage.setItem(title, JSON.stringify({
                    "title": title,
                    "start": start,
                    "end": end,
                    "allDay": allDay
                }))
            };
            //Render the event object and make it "stick"
            calendar.fullCalendar("renderEvent", newEvent, true);
        }
        //Remove the selection on exiting the event creation
        calendar.fullCalendar("unselect");
        //Get the events from storage
        var storedEvents = [];
        for (title in localStorage) {
            storedEvents = localStorage.getItem(title);
            //(testing only. getItem is now successful. To now render on the document this code must go to calendar.js)
            console.log(storedEvents);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by hoisting up the storedEvents from the function (also separated into another function and in another file):

My fullcalendar.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({   
       //...
       eventSources: [
            {
                //source1 a google calendar url
            },
            {
                events: localStorageEventFetcher()
            }
        ],
        select: eventCreaterOnSelection
        //...
    });
});
```

My eventCreatorOnSelection.js:

```
eventCreaterOnSelection = function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt("Event Title:");
    var allDay;
    var save = [];
    if (title) {
        allDay = confirm("All Day event?");
        var newEvent = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay,
        };
        save.push(localStorage.setItem(title, JSON.stringify(newEvent)));
        calendar.fullCalendar("renderEvent", newEvent, true);
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar("unselect");
}
```

My new localStorageEventFetcher.js file:

```
localStorageEventFetcher = function(title) {
    var storedEvents = [];
    for (title in localStorage) {
        storedEvents.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(title)));
    }    
    return storedEvents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are initializing the calendar twice (basically the whichever one is called 2nd is the only calendar created). If you want to separate your events code just return an object with the appropriate values from a method in the events.js (or I guess you could just create the variable on the global scope), you would then need to combine this with the event object you are using in your calendar.js (have a look at jquery functions merge or extend for this, I can't remember which one would be more appropriate)
2. Not sure what the issue is. What is local storage? How is it related to your google calendar events? You should probably be using eventSources, as this allows you specify multiple sources.
3. eventRender runs for every event. I would assume there are 3 events being returned from your call to google calendar, you then run eventRender for each of these, which leads to your 3 calls

Comment: 1 and 3.  I managed to make the event creation on selection to work (I declared $("#calendar") as a global variable (calendar = $("#calendar") ), however the instantiation problem remains (I call the calendar 3 times as you correctly pointed out). If you really could point me out how I could do this without instatiating again I would appreciate it. I looked at the merge and extend functions and I don't see how I can apply them to this case.

2. localstorage is an HTML5 API for storing data (like webstorage and indexedDB). If I wanted I could use a database instead, but in this case its this.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the localstorage.getitem() method working once instead of 3 times. Problem was that storedEvents wasn't an array, not the 3 calls to Fullcalendar (those are needed to get the Full Calendar methods), silly me.

Now I need to render the events in localstorage when the document loads (another thing I was approaching incorrectly: the events should load not on the select method, but on document load, obviously, silly me again.)

Comment: For your new 2 it seems like you need [events as array](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/) or possibly [events as a function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/). It might be best to reproduce on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) though, as I'm finding it hard to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: The problem is solve... it was again a silly me: I forgot that the storedEvents needed to be hoisted up. I'll upload the code soon.