# Call fullcalendar function from another file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar-5

Am using full-calendar V.5, I need to call full-calendar function from another page. But encountering error of **calendar.______  is not a function**
I have checked this [Calling a fullcalendar method/callback from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792215/calling-a-fullcalendar-method-callback-from-another-file) , but not working for version 5.

**Press the sidebar toggle button,to see error**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
    });

    calendar.render();
   
  });
   $('.icon').click(function(){
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass('in');
      calendar.render();
    });
```

```css
.sidebar{
  background:#eeeeee;
  height:100vh;
  width:200px;  
}
.h-100{
  height:100vh!important;
}
.main{
  flex:1;
  padding:20px
}
.icon{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.in{
  width:25px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <div class="sidebar in">
    <div class="icon text-right px-2">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-text-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="main">
     <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring **calendar**  variable globally? Try declaring it above the addEventListener and check.

Comment: Can you explain how to declare it outside ? I don't understand fully.@dee

Answer (score 1):

calendar variable is not in the scope of the $(".icon") function that may encounter the error. Try using this.

```js
let calendar;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
    });

    calendar.render();
   
  });
   $('.icon').click(function(){
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass('in');
      calendar.render();
    });
```

```css
.sidebar{
  background:#eeeeee;
  height:100vh;
  width:200px;  
}
.h-100{
  height:100vh!important;
}
.main{
  flex:1;
  padding:20px
}
.icon{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.in{
  width:25px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <div class="sidebar in">
    <div class="icon text-right px-2">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-text-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="main">
     <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A better a solution would be to put `$('.icon').click(function()` inside the DOMContentLoaded block - it should be there anyway for safety, to ensure the page has entirely loaded before trying to attach event listeners to objects within it

Comment: @ADyson . I mentioned it early that the `$('.icon').click(function()` is not in the same page as DOMContentLoaded block, Putting it inside isn't possible because both are different pages

Comment: @Amalnandan you never specifically mentioned it. There was something vague about "another page", but no real clarity of what that meant in practice. You need to edit the question and clarify the scenario...is the "other page" loaded into the page you're using via AJAX, perhaps? Or are both pages open in the broswser in separate tabs? Or is one page loaded after another? All of those are different scenarios with different possible problems and solutions. Make an update to your post and give us the exact situation you are trying to control, please.